# Comparing two mysql tables and saving differences in third

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to compare two different tables and to save unmatched records in third. Assume we have one table `t1`:

```
1stID, Title, Forename, Surname, Postcode, 
   t1field1, t1field2, t1field3 ....
```

second table `t2`:

```
2ndID, 2nd_title, 2nd_forename, 2nd_surname, 
   2nd_postcode, 2nd_field1, 2ndfield2 ...
```

and third empty table `t3` with structure just as table `t2`.

There are many thousands of records and many additional fields in both tables. IDs are completely different. The only way is to **compare using forename, surname and postcode when they are not empty** in 1st table. Of course result can be inaccurate, but it'll be ok for me now.

What is the best way to compare `t1` table with `t2` table using one MySQL statement and save **unmatched** records from table `t2` in table `t3`?

I can construct mysql statement in PHPMyAdmin or directly in console.

I've searched the web and there are many ways to do a select, but there is no answer how to populate 3rd table and how to use non-ID columns to compare. Thanks for response.

Comment: I think SQL-Server is unrelated here. Don't tag the products which are not involved.

Comment: Are the column names same for `t1` and `t2` tables?

Comment: No, column names are totally different. Only title, forename, surname and postcode values are present in both tables (however column names differ).

Answer (score 0):

Collecting all records where `not in` from table_2 and insert in table_3

```
insert into table_3 
select * from table_1 where 
forename not  in (select * from table_2)
or surname not in (select * from table_2)
or postcode not  in (select * from table_2)
```

`OR` can be change to `AND` operator if you want to filter all